# Angular js cycle when declare component

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular js module

```
var appModule = angular.module('appModule', ['datatables','ngMaterial', 'ui.select'])
```

when i declare a new component using my `appModule`, I refresh my app in browser but it creates a request load cycle in XHR and my app breaks

```
appModule.component('myCustomTable', {
        templateUrl: 'table-component',
        controller: function () {
                this.user = {
                        name: 'user name'
                };
        }
});
```

Am using AngularJS 1.65

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might happen because your controller is an anonymous function.

(According to: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_03)

```
appModule.component('myCustomTable', {
        templateUrl: 'table-component',
        controller: function () { // <- Here
                this.user = {
                        name: 'user name'
                };
        }
});
```